# Disable click on drawerlayout hamburger icon when show progress bar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I has activity with the next layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#4777">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/widgetRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Container `containerProgress`(progressBar) is show over all other elements in screen. 
OK.

I need when `containerProgress` is show to was not possible to click any items on screen.

But I can click on `drawerlayout hamburger icon`. 
How I can `disable click on hamburger icon` while `containerProgress` is show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set empty click listener to toggle

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    // We ignore it
}
```

And whem you want to enable it again:

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(null);
```

**OR**

You can hide it using

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

**OR**

If under "disable click" you mean "prevent drawer to be opened" you can do that:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
```

And when you want to enable it:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
```

Comment: Under progressBar I has many items. So I wan't to dissable click every of them. How I can do this?

Comment: @Alexei for(I=0;I<root.getViewCount();I++){root.getViewAt(I).setEnabled(false);}

Comment: Has more simple solution. I set android:clickable="true" to progressBar. And  as result when progress is show , all items under progress are not clickable.

Comment: @Alexei yeah, it also works, progress handles all clicks and they do not go to other views